# Multithreading iOS with segmented control

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading

I have the following task to do:
I have a `segmented control` with two main tabs, the first tab has to load ads and data from the network, each of them is via different urls. What I want to do is query the ads and the data in parallel, after both of them have finished, I want to merge them into a single list and display it to the user. This can be done with a `DispatchGroup` easily using `.enter()` and `.leave()`. However since this is in a `segmented control` with a `search bar`. The `DispatchGroup` needs to be **cancellable** in order for a new set of ads and data to be loaded. Is there a way to cancel the `DispatchGroup`, or is there a way to achieve this logic via other multithreading functionality?

Comment: does this cover it https://stackoverflow.com/q/46276389/3218273

Comment: i saw that question, but i doesn't, that answers the case for the DispatchGroup to stop waiting, not for it to be cancelled

Comment: Have you tried https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsoperationqueue? It includes support to cancel operations.

Comment: so this means that there's no way to cancel a `DispatchGroup`?

Comment: No. You need to use NSOperationQueue for such tasks.

Comment: Think, do you really need to combine the news feed together? In most cases, asynchronous parallel loading is preferable.
To stop the task you can use **OperationQueue** or **DispatchWorkItem** with concurrent DispatchQueue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly the kind of thing that Combine is good for (if you are using iOS 13). ie you can make your network requests a function of the currently selected segment and what is typed in search bar and when you call `switchToLatest` it will cancel any uncompleted requests and only leave the most request that reflects the most recent state alive.  I just wrote and example that does exactly that here:
https://github.com/joshuajhomann/Combine-NasaMediaSearch

Or more succinctly, setup two passthrough subjects, one for your search bar and one for your segmented control, combine them into a network request, flatten it with `switchToLatest, then assign the result wherever you need it:

```
  private var data: [MyData] = []
  private var searchTermSubject = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()
  private var segmentSubject = PassthroughSubject<SegmentType, Never>()

...

    let searchResults = Publishers
      .CombineLatest(
        searchTermSubject,
        segmentSubject
      )
      .debounce(for: .milliseconds(250), scheduler: RunLoop.main)
      .map { combined -> AnyPublisher<[MyData],Never> in
        let (term, segmentType) = combined
        guard !(term.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).isEmpty) else {
          return Just(.empty).eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
        return NetworkRequestPublisher
          .search(query: term, mediaType: segmentType)
          .replaceErrorWith([])
          .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    .switchToLatest()
    .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
    // assign or sink here depending on what you want to do
```

If you are not using iOS 13 then you can use OperationQueue or simply call cancel on the data task yourself.